# How to save coordinates from with openlayers ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I want to save my coordinates from the frontend to the backend and I don't know how to send them.
the coordinates are saved in a JS array and I don't know how to transfer them to C#.

HTML, CSS & JS for the map

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/ol.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/ol-ext.css">


        <script src="~/js/ol.js"></script>

        <script src="~/js/ol-ext.js"></script>

        @*<script src="~/js/elm-pep"></script>*@

        @*<script src="~/js/JavaScript.js"></script>*@



        <div id="map" style="width:600px; height:400px;">
            <div class="photon ol-search ol-unselectable ol-control ol-collapsed">
                <input asp-for="coordinates" type="search" class="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search...">
                <input asp-for="coordinates" type="button" class="ol-revers" title="click on the map">
                <ul class="autocomplete history">
                    <li data-search="0"> 398<i> 9350004 Jérusalem (Israël)</i></li>
                    <li class="copy"><a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="new">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="button-70" style="z-index:1;" id="location-button">
            @*<button id="location-button" title="Get your location"></button>*@
            @*<button asp-for="coordinates" class="button-70" id="location-button" role="button" title="Get your current location"> Get cuttent location</button>*@
            <input asp-for="coordinates" type="button" value=" Get cuttent location" id="location-button" />
        </div>


        <style>
            .button-70 #location-button {
                background: none;
                border: none;
                transform: scale(2)
            }

            .button-70 {
                transform: scale(0.7);
                background-image: linear-gradient(#0dccea, #0d70ea);
                border: 0;
                border-radius: 4px;
                box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 0 5px 15px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                color: #fff;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
                font-size: .9em;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 10px 15px;
                text-align: center;
                user-select: none;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                touch-action: manipulation;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var layers = [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })];

            var map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map',
                view: new ol.View({
                    zoom: 5,
                    center: [166326, 5992663]
                }),
                interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: false, pinchRotate: false }),
                layers: layers
            });

            var search = new ol.control.SearchPhoton({
                lang: "fr",
                reverse: true,
                position: true
            });
            map.addControl(search);

            var markers;
            search.on('select', function (e) {

                map.getView().animate({
                    center: e.coordinate,
                    zoom: Math.max(map.getView().getZoom(), 16)
                });

                loc(e.coordinate);
            });

            function loc(e) {
                console.log(e);
                if (markers) {
                    map.removeLayer(markers)
                }

                markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                    style: new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon({
                            anchor: [0.5, 1],
                            src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png' // => https://app.uploadcare.com/projects/c05bbeb5e1a61e862903/files/7110cd57-b0ee-4833-bcd1-ff0343dd01cc/?limit=100&ordering=-datetime_uploaded
                        })
                    })
                });

                map.addLayer(markers);

                var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(e));
                markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);

            }

            const options = {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 5000,
                maximumAge: 0
            };

            document.querySelector("#location-button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                        console.log(e);
                        if (markers) {
                            map.removeLayer(markers)
                        }

                        markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                            source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                            style: new ol.style.Style({
                                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                                    anchor: [0.5, 1],
                                    src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png' // => https://app.uploadcare.com/projects/c05bbeb5e1a61e862903/files/7110cd57-b0ee-4833-bcd1-ff0343dd01cc/?limit=100&ordering=-datetime_uploaded
                                })
                            })
                        });

                        map.addLayer(markers);

                        function success(pos) {
                            const crd = pos.coords;

                            console.log('Your current position is:');
                            console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
                            console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
                            console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
                            return new Array(crd.latitude, crd.longitude);
                        }

                        function error(err) {
                            console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
                        }

                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

                        var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude])));
                        markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
                }
            });
        </script>
```

I tried to save the coordinates in A list and in a string, but none worked.
here is the Model code:

```
public class ReportModel
{
    //...stuff...
    public string coordinates { get; set; }
    //...more stuff...
}
```

ReportDAO.cs - Saves the given data form the user

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using SvivaTeamVersion3.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SvivaTeamVersion3.Services
{
    public class ReportDAO
    {
        static readonly string connectionString = @"KEY";
        public static bool addReport(ReportModel report)
        {
            bool success = false;
            string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO dbo.Reports (category,title,description,statUrgence,cordsLat,cordsLong) VALUES (@category,@title,@description,@statUrgence,@cordsLat,@cordsLong)";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);

                command.Parameters.Add("@category", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 32).Value = report.category;
                command.Parameters.Add("@title", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 32).Value = report.title;
                command.Parameters.Add("@description", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = report.remarks;
                command.Parameters.Add("@statUrgence", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = report.statUrgence;
                command.Parameters.Add("@cordsLat", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float).Value = report.coordinates;
                command.Parameters.Add("@cordsLong", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float).Value = 0;
                //I've tried to merge the lat and long to a single string, didn't work.
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

                return success;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to send them in a json string format, you need to serialize and deserialize the json string. You could deserialize the json manually here: https://json2csharp.com/ and copy paste the classes

Comment: How do I send them in a json string format?

Comment: Post request, how do you communicate with your server?

Comment: If I understood you correctly then I have an SQL server.
On the same page, I have a button "Add Report" when I click on it activates the Controller, the controller call's a DAO (reportDAO.cs) class there I have a function that takes a given ReportModel and uploads it to the server. I'll add the DAO code rn.

Comment: Never heard of reportdao it seems that you first need to learn the basics of server client communication

Comment: Does it really matter? I just want to save the coordinates into a variable.

Comment: So your problem is not about how you can send your data to the server but why you can’t save the coordinates into the database? Do you have any error messages?

Comment: My problem is to get it from the site to the Model class. Even before I send it to the DB.

Comment: Like I said, post request.

Comment: what do you mean by a request

Comment: I saw a video that explains what it is but I don't have a URL right now so how exactly I do this?

Comment: You need to communicate to your server in the backend that you like to save somehting into the database, to to that you need a api in your backend like rest-api. So in you backend you would have a method like "saveCoordinates" you call this method (from client side) with a post request. In the request body you would pass the parameters like your coordinates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request

Comment: How can I see the new link that I get back? when I press the send button the link doesn't change, after clicking it stays https://localhost:PORT/.../ and not change to https://localhost:PORT/.../values